# Compare the value of a checked radio button and the submit button value

Tags: javascript, loops, button, radio-button, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a multiple choice quiz that uses radio buttons and a `<button>` inside a `<fieldset>`. The correct answer is stored inside the `value` attribute of the `<button>` and I want to compare the value of a checked radio button if it matches the value of the associated (in its own fieldset) `<button>`. However, I am not getting any result on the console on button click.

The steps I have done or am trying to do are below:

1. Get each fieldset
2. Get each fieldset's radio buttons
3. Get the associated fieldset button
4. Add a click event listener for the button to check if the value of
   each fieldset radio button matches the value of its associated
   button
5. If the button is clicked, check if the checked radio button value
   matches the button value in that fieldset, `console.log("CORRECT")`,
   else if wrong, `console.log("WRONG")`, else
   `console.log("SKIPPED")`.

```js
var quizArea = document.getElementById("quiz-area");
var fieldsets = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset"); // step 1
//console.log(fieldsets, fieldsets.length, typeof fieldsets);

for (var s = 0; s < fieldsets.length; s++) {
  var fieldsetChoices = fieldsets[s].querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]"); // step 2  //console.log("fieldsetChoices[s]",fieldsetChoices[s]);

  for (var i; i < fieldsetChoices.length; i++) { //console.log("fieldsetChoices[i]",fieldsetChoices[i];
    var fieldsetButton = fieldsets[s].querySelector("button[type=button]"); // step 3
    //console.log("fieldsetButton", fieldsetButton, fieldsetButton.value, typeof fieldsetButton);

    fieldsetButton.addEventListener("click", function() { // step 4
      if (fieldsetChoices[i].checked) {
        if (fieldsetChoices[i].value == fieldsetButton.value) { // step 5
          console.log("CORRECT", fieldsetChoices[i].value);
        } else {
          console.log("WRONG", fieldsetChoices[i].value);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("SKIPPED", fieldsetChoices[i].value);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
}

legend {
  font-weight: bold;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: .5rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}


/*legend>*{text-align:center;}*/

input[type=radio] {
  float: left;
  margin-right: .5rem;
}

.submit-button {
  display: block;
  margin: .5rem auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='quiz-area'>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>What is the capital of Indonesia?</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" class="quiz-choices" id="indonesia-jakarta-0" name="Indonesia" value="Jakarta">Jakarta</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="quiz-choices" id="indonesia-kuala-lumpur-0" name="Indonesia" value="Kuala Lumpur">Kuala Lumpur</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="quiz-choices" id="indonesia-manila-0" name="Indonesia" value="Manila">Manila</label>
    <button type="button" value="Jakarta">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>What is the capital of Malaysia?</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" class="quiz-choices" id="malaysia-jakarta-1" name="Malaysia" value="Jakarta">Jakarta</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="quiz-choices" id="malaysia-manila-1" name="Malaysia" value="Manila">Manila</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="quiz-choices" id="malaysia-kuala-lumpur-1" name="Malaysia" value="Kuala Lumpur">Kuala Lumpur</label>
    <button type="button" value="Kuala Lumpur">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>What is the capital of Philippines?</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" class="quiz-choices" id="philippines-jakarta-2" name="Philippines" value="Jakarta">Jakarta</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="quiz-choices" id="philippines-kuala-lumpur-2" name="Philippines" value="Kuala Lumpur">Kuala Lumpur</label>
    <label><input type="radio" class="quiz-choices" id="philippines-manila-2" name="Philippines" value="Manila">Manila</label>
    <button type="button" value="Manila">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>

</div>
```

Comment: You are using the same variable `i` as the index in both the loops!

Comment: @KunalKukreja: Thank you for pointing this out. I have modified the code above, but it now does not give any results in the console log, and I do not know what is causing it. Please help.